# Poor answer to poor question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits, specific-answer

I failed an audit for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6745088) (now deleted).  The question was (in my opinion) a low-quality question to begin with since it asked for a "free tool," which falls into an off-topic category.

The answer in question was short (picture at bottom). The question itself was flaggable on its own, which leads to lower quality answers.

I mostly agree with the comment there (visible only after the audit), but the answer is not quite link-only.  It mentions a tool called `dbff`. A Google search for `dbff mysql` returns the link in the answer as the first hit. What more could the answerer include beyond a name, description, and link for such a tool?

Why is this answer considered poor quality? Also, would it be appropriate to comment that the question itself is low-quality when judging an answer?

[image: Failed audit answer]

Comment: Answers to questions asking for links are answers (which is why we are supposed to just close the question). The audit system doesn't know that though... Also, the question is quite old, which may explain the initial non-closure.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes that makes sense.  So does that mean that my action was correct?  Or is there a better "more-correct" way to handle that?

Comment: The rule I quoted is intended to prevent *flagging* such answers, so you could argue that declining the flag (by selecting "Looks OK") is reasonable, even though it may go against most reviewers who correctly identify the link-answer without seeing the question. Definitely flag the question for closure though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Whatever you do, go to the question and vote/flag to close/delete.

What happens to the answer to the question is largely irrelevant, because the question should eventually end up being deleted anyway, taking the answer along with it.

---

It's deleted now.

Comment: Yes that makes sense (and the question is now closed).  So for the purposes of this audit, is there any proper way of marking the answer as "answer of a question that should be closed"

Comment: @ryanyuyu You can just skip it.  It's a crap answer, it's just not worth taking the time to go around trying to delete it *in addition* to voting to delete the question.  Of course, it's not worth taking the time to actively try to save it either.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'll keep that in mind for future reviews.

Comment: So far as I can tell, skipping an audit is basically never judged as wrong.

Comment: @Kevin So, that's the secret!