# Is this an edge case of asking for 3rd party resource and link only answer?

Tags: discussion

I just encountered [this Q&A pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819650/rtmp-c-client-library). While I first down- and close voted, because of the question seemingly looked like asking for a 3rd party resource recommendation, I edited it a bit for better titles of the links and it doesn't really do so. It's just short cutting some of the steps taken for a solution approach.

An answer came up on the question, which is obviously a link-only answer, but perfectly fitting what the question needs to fix the problem.

How to handle this actually? Is all of that on-topic or not?

I personally don't like all of that link only stuff, but for any researcher after that particular problem it may make enough sense (hopefully the links don't decay).

<sub>I've done and retracted all of my voting there now BTW, so I can't influence further processing anymore.</sub>

Comment: Hmm, IMO it's a bit too much of a library/tool recommendation.  I think it's off-topic.  The answer is not quite link only, but a result of the bad question.

Comment: I'd say the question is the main problem.  [This situation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283500/poor-answer-to-poor-question) actually came up for me on an audit, so I usually lean towards closing the question and leaving the answer.  The answer is ok, and more the result of a poor question.

Comment: Of course now the question has been edited into an acceptable form so much of my commentary is no longer applicable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've edited it yet again. The problem is pretty basic, but it doesn't appear that he's asking for a 3rd-party recommendation *at all* - nor has he received one: the answer, while short, is not link-only:

> You probably downloaded the prebuilt binary. You need the source which includes librtmp library.

...which probably *is* more or less the answer he needs. That it follows up with a link doesn't hurt its usefulness any.

Comment: You confirm my hesitations and doubts for closing it :)