# Failed review answer audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed the following [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7646058). I first thought the answer was bad, as it contains basically only a link. However, when looking at the corresponding [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041846/any-postgres-compatible-orm-for-node-js), all other answers where pretty much of the same type.

So I thought, for completeness, this might be ok, as the question has 16k views and might be a google entry point and the new library mentioned seemed reasonable to me.

I still don't see why the answer should not be at the question. Rather, the question itself is offtopic as asking for a library. What is the right course of action here?

Comment: [Something similar happened to me](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283500/poor-answer-to-poor-question).  The consensus was "Skip" then manually go to the question and flag/vote to close.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Ok, I was unsure about flagging very old posts, but yes this advice is consistent.

Comment: Yeah, just closing old questions is fine (they aren't necessarily deleted).  It prevents new (probably bad) answers from being posted.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a comment like Dan McGrath.  I do agree that since the question is off topic and should be flagged for:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic...